# Looping in command prompt: Shared licence conundrum

Tags: command-prompt

We work on a shared license and its access works on a first-come-first-serve basis. Thus, I need a command prompt line which will keep attempting to run the software until I can access the license.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are tried already?

Comment: FOR %i IN (C:\Desktop\Furnace\Lobo.mat) DO Run %i